# Need help in adding space to a nav list in CCS3

Tags: html

I need to add a space in between some of the items in a nav list but not sure how.  Some help would be appreciated.

Here is the HTML

```html
<nav>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="tss_home.html">Home Page</a></li>
         <li><a href="tss_run.html">Running Class</a></li>
         <li><a href="tss_bike.html">Cycling Class</a></li>
         <li><a href="tss_swim.html">Swimming Class</a></li>
         <li><a href="tss_coach.html">Coaches</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.active.com/">Active.com</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.runnersworld.com/">Runner's World</a></li>
         <li><a href="https://www.endomondo.com/">endomondo.com</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.strava.com/">Strava</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.bicycling.com/">Bicycling Magazine</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://velonews.competitor.com/">VeloNews</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://bicycletutor.com/">Bicycle Tutor</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.swimsmooth.com/">Swim Smooth</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.swimmingworldmagazine.com/">Swimming World</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.usaswimming.org/">USA Swimming</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.triathlon.org/">triathlon.org</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.usatriathlon.org/">usatriathlon.org</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.trifind.com/tx.html">Texas Triathlons</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.captextri.com/">CapTex Triathlon</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.trifind.com/">Triathlon Calendar</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://triathlon.competitor.com/">Triathlete.com</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.trifuel.com/">Trifuel.com</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
```

I need to put a space between the 5th and 6th line and between the 15th and 16th.  Not sure how to do it in the CCS.

Comment: what do you mean by putting a space exactly ? How about putting an empty <li></li> between those lines ?

Comment: horizontal or vertical?  :D

Answer (score 3):

Give 5th & 15th an ID ...
Then write in CSS Codes :

```
<style>
nav ul li.one {margin-bottom:25px;}
nav ul li.two {margin-top:25px;}
</style>
```

**In HTML:**

```
<li class="one"><a href="tss_coach.html">Coaches</a></li>
<li class="two"><a href="http://www.active.com/">Active.com</a></li>
```

do the same with 15 and 16

Comment: If I read your HTML Semantic code, how I can understand the meaning of « one » and « two » in this website list link context? Also the selector is too precise, « nav .one » and « nav .two » with `nav` as context is good enough.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved in CSS3 by using the nth-child

```
nav ul li:nth-child(6), nav ul li:nth-child(16)
{
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: nice and simple coding

Comment: Use `:nth-child` in the <ul> or <ol> force each <li> to be dependent of there place. `:nth-child` is more useful in `layout` context or `grid` context not into `data` context.

Answer (score 1):

In the `<li>` put a margin like so `<li style="margin-top: 20px">`. That will give you extra spacing above. You can change top to bottom/left/right and the pixels for customizing.

Answer (score 0):

try to add padding/margin to those li tags

```
<li style="padding-right:3px"><a href="tss_coach.html">Coaches</a></li>
<li  style="padding-left:3px"><a href="http://www.active.com/">Active.com</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Add a class to those li elements you want space around. Do this like so:

```
    <li class="space">
```

Then You could add padding or margins to the CSS file or between

```
    <style></style>
```

tags in the html document.

```
    .space { margin: 10px; }
    .space { padding: 10px; }
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a good reason why you want exactly add some space to this positions, so:

**To avoid to modify CSS file each time an entry is added**

Add some `:nth-child` is not a good solution. If tomorrow you add a new item, your space will not be in the correct place.

**To Avoid a semantic meaning confusion**

Add some `<li>&nbsp;</li>` is not a good solution too because a `<li>` (list item) must contain same semantic thing (in `<ol>` (ordered list) or `<ul>` (unordered list) each item are the same purpose, else use `<div>`  insteed). If there is some « empty » item, this is not a list item anymore. For example, if you list link from a database, create empty item just for « design » is not good, because this force you to add some « empty data ».

**To allow Semantic and Design to fit**

You do first define « why this item need more space », « why this item is different » ? For example: « because this item is a very important item » so tag item as `important` (or others).

After that, just apply your specific CSS for `.important` item on your list for example.

```css
 /**
  * List all link to navigate into website.
  * @component .main-navigation
  */
.main-navigation {}

/**
  * Set an item as important in a list of item.
  * @pattern .important
  * @partof  .main-navigation
  * @example <ul>
  *     <li class="important">This is important</li>
  *     <li>This is less important</li>
  * </ul>
  */
.main-navigation .important {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-navigation">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="tss_home.html">Home Page</a></li>
         <li><a href="tss_run.html">Running Class</a></li>
         <li><a href="tss_bike.html">Cycling Class</a></li>
         <li><a href="tss_swim.html">Swimming Class</a></li>

         <li class="important"><a href="tss_coach.html">Coaches</a></li>

         <li><a href="http://www.active.com/">Active.com</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.runnersworld.com/">Runner's World</a></li>
         <li><a href="https://www.endomondo.com/">endomondo.com</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.strava.com/">Strava</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.bicycling.com/">Bicycling Magazine</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://velonews.competitor.com/">VeloNews</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://bicycletutor.com/">Bicycle Tutor</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.swimsmooth.com/">Swim Smooth</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.swimmingworldmagazine.com/">Swimming World</a></li>

         <li class="important"><a href="http://www.usaswimming.org/">USA Swimming</a></li>

         <li><a href="http://www.triathlon.org/">triathlon.org</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.usatriathlon.org/">usatriathlon.org</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.trifind.com/tx.html">Texas Triathlons</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.captextri.com/">CapTex Triathlon</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.trifind.com/">Triathlon Calendar</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://triathlon.competitor.com/">Triathlete.com</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.trifuel.com/">Trifuel.com</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
```

Name the `.important` class as you want but not `.space` for example, because if tomorrow you want change the design not with space but with color differenciation, your class will not be correctly named. But an item important will always be important. If it's not the case anymore, just « untag » it by removing class.

If tomorrow or later you want add some link between your existing link, no change in CSS will be needed.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant? Because I have read « but not sure how. Some help would be appreciated ». Strange...